# PyQt5 how to update QLabel as an animation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I want to use my qlabel as a countdown. Basically when countdown is called the label changes " 3  2  1  begin", with 1 second gap in-between .

however, if I do this:

```
def nextSound(self):

    self.mainLabel.setText("3")

    sleep(1)

    self.mainLabel.setText("2")

    sleep(1)
    self.mainLabel.setText("1")
```

it simply just wait until the end without updating the label. So I try to use `QPropertyAnimation`:

```
  def nextSound(self):

        self.animate = QPropertyAnimation(self.mainLabel,"setText")

        self.animate.setDuration(1000)
        self.animate.startValue("3")
        self.animate.setEndValue("2")
        self.animate.start()
```

But received this error:

```
self.animate = QPropertyAnimation(self.mainLabel,"setText")
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPropertyAnimation(parent: QObject = None): too many arguments
  QPropertyAnimation(QObject, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray], parent: QObject = None): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPropertyAnimation` is based on interpolating the values that a q-property takes, when wanting to use setText I think that the closest thing is the q-property text but the texts can not be interpolated so a solution would be to create a q-property that takes numerical value.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class NumLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def number(self):
        try:
            return int(self.text())
        except:
            return 0
    def setNumber(self, number):
        self.setNum(number)
    number = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, fget=number, fset=setNumber)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = NumLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(w, b'number')
    animation.setStartValue(3)
    animation.setEndValue(0)
    animation.setDuration(1000*(abs(animation.endValue() - animation.startValue())))
    animation.start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another best option is to use `QTimeLine`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    start = 3
    end = 0
    timeLine = QtCore.QTimeLine(abs(end - start)*1000, w)
    timeLine.setFrameRange(start, end)
    timeLine.frameChanged.connect(w.setNum)

    # set start value
    w.setNum(start)
    # start timer
    timeLine.start()

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you! I used the QTimeLine and set the curve shape to Linear. It works.